# Java 3D API - Prevent small texture blurriness

Tags: java, scaling, java-3d, texturing

[image: At the bottom of the 3D image, the blurriness is clear.]

I have rendered this scene using the Java 3D API. At the bottom of the image, where the ground is closer to the viewer, there is a blurriness surrounding the black lines on the image. I would like to prevent this blurriness entirely. Here is the image I am using as the texture:

[image: grid.png]

As you can see, it is quite small but making the image larger is not an option. Are there any scaling methods I can change the type of such as a "nearest-neighbour" option for Java 3D texturing?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [Texture.setMagFilter](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.3.2/javax/media/j3d/Texture.html#setMagFilter\(int\))([BASE_LEVEL_POINT](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.3.2/javax/media/j3d/Texture.html#BASE_LEVEL_POINT))?

Answer (score 0):

As Banthar suggested, I used:

```
texture.setMagFilter(Texture.BASE_LEVEL_POINT‌​);
```

and it works perfectly with no blurriness.